# Unable to write the parameter to sink in adf data flow

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am currently learning ADF and exploring Azure stack. I am facing below issue.

In below Dataflow, I am taking system parameters from pipeline ( e.g. Pipeline name, runID etc) and passing to dataflow. Finally I am writing into sink which is Text File. However, Only able to see the column names in Text File and not any values. Please advice.

[image]

This is the output I am getting :-

[image]

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**A file like above will be generated only when your source file rows are 0 apart from the header**.

As per your dataflow design, you are using a`dummy` column header in your source file and trying to create additional columns from pipeline values.

Here, the target file rows generated by dataflow will be same as the source file rows. So, make sure your source file has at least one row to generate the proper results like below.

[image]

**Result file after pipeline run:**

[image]

If your source rows are 3, then dataflow will also generate 3 rows like below.

[image]

Also, you can achieve the same using copy activity as well.

Give your dataset to copy activity source and go to **Additonal columns** section in it. In that, create additional column and add the required pipeline system parameters from the dynamic content expression.

[image]

Add your sink dataset and then go to mapping. In the mapping, **Import schemas** and give any sample string values to the columns like below.

[image]

Now, it will show all the input columns. Here, delete the extra source column.

[image]

Run the pipeline and it will give the desired results in the sink file. For this method also, the output rows depend on input rows. So, the input should have at least one row as same as above.

Comment: Yes. That's answer my question. Thank you!